# Ajax post method not working in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax post not working in my code i don't know what exact problem the original code (controller code) please help me

```
class Ajax_post extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();  
$this->load->helper(array('url'));
}

function index()
{

$this->load->view('ajax_post');
}

function post_action()
{

if(($_POST['username'] == "") || ($_POST['password'] == ""))
{
  $message = "Please fill up blank fields";
  $bg_color = "#FFEBE8";

}elseif(($_POST['username'] != "myusername") || ($_POST['password'] != "mypassword")){
  $message = "Username and password do not match.";
  $bg_color = "#FFEBE8";

}else{
  $message = "Username and password matched.";
  $bg_color = "#FFA";
}

$output = '{ "message": "'.$message.'", "bg_color": "'.$bg_color.'" }';

}
}

?>
```

This is my view page code

```
    <div id="form_message"></div>
    <form name="ajax_form" id ="ajax_form" method="post">

      Username/Email:*<input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="30" /><br/><br/>
      Password:*<input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="30" /><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="login_submit" id="login_submit" onClick="getData();"/>

  </form>
</div>
```

This is my javascript code (ajax_post.js)

```
  function getData(){

    var username=$("#username").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();      
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/ajax_post/post_action",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
    cache:false,
    success: 
      function(data){
          alert(data);
          }
     // $("#form_message").html(data.message).css({'background-color' : data.bg_color}).fadeIn('slow'); 


});
}
 </body>
```

i stuck with this thing for whole day..

please anyone show me the right way to do the controller and js code.

Answer (score 3):

you are not making a POST request, try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //notice the change
```

by specifying the `type` as `POST` you will be able to make a POST request

or you can use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

here is link to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

EDIT

on click of the submit button you need to cancel the default behavior of the form submit like

```
function getData() {
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/ajax_post/post_action",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{username:username,password:password},
    cache:false,
    success:function (data) {
      alert(data);
    }  
  });
 return false;
}
```

Comment: try debugging the code using firebug or chrome developer tools

Answer (score 2):

in fact, you are making a 'GET' request as you've mentioned `type: "GET"`. here is your modified js code.

```
function getData() {
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/ajax_post/post_action",
    dataType:"json",
    data:"username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
    cache:false,
    success:function (data) {
      alert(data);
    }
    // $("#form_message").html(data.message).css({'background-color' : data.bg_color}).fadeIn('slow');
  });
}
```

Edit:
try the following code. remove the onclick attribute and its value from the submit button

```
$('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/ajax_post/post_action",
    dataType:"json",
    data:"username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
    cache:false,
    success:function (data) {
      alert(data);
    }
    // $("#form_message").html(data.message).css({'background-color' : data.bg_color}).fadeIn('slow');
  });
  return false;
})
```

Comment: please explain 'not working'. do you get any error? what exactly happens when you hit the submit button?

Comment: I have try this code in CI framework and its working fine for me. I have call a controller method to receive this call from ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I see whats not working here.

use

```
onClick="getData(); return false;" // in your submit button
```

or

```
function getData(e){
e.preventDefault();
//your code
```

or

```
success: 
  function(data){
      alert(data);
return false;
      }
error : function(){
return false;
}
//stops the default dom form submission after success
```

make sure jquery is loaded!

and make sure if you are using other javascripts there is no error in any function, use console window to see js error

Comment: also, its not good practice to just use javascript for form submission.

what if javascript is disabled, or what if some of your javascript isnt working. Use both the methods.

on your controller, check if ajax request, return json then.

if not ajax request, return html with errors.!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you’re using $_POST. use $this->input->post(’var’) or get.
secondly youre not returning json data.
use this instead.

```
$.ajax(’url’).done(function(data){
$(’#message’).html(data);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the exact callback data? I don't personally construct a json string.
You may try making an array of data

```
$data = array();
$data['message'] = //assign here ;
$data['bg_color'] = //assign here ;
```

Then use json_encode for output.

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

That code will generate the json string to you.
You can easily grab the data in your js callback like these

```
data.message
data.bg_color
```

This code helps me a lot. Hope it helps.

Comment: also, use 3nigma's way of initializing post data in your js, that is more efficient because you don't have to construct the post data string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

function getData(){

```
var username=$("#username").val();
var password=$("#password").val();      
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/ajax_post/post_action",
dataType: "json",
data: {username : username , password :password},
cache:false,
success: 
  function(data){
      alert(data);
      }
 // $("#form_message").html(data.message).css({'background-color' : data.bg_color}).fadeIn('slow');
```

});
}